# how to filter nested related django objects

Tags: django, django-models, django-rest-framework

I have an app with lots of investors that invest in the same rounds, which belong to companies, as seen below. However when a user(investor) is logged in, i only want him to be able to see HIS investments.

```
    {
        "id": 1,
        "name": "Technology Company",
        "rounds": [
            {
                "id": 1,
                "kind": "priced round",
                "company": 1,
                "investments": [
                    {
                        "id": 1,
                        "investor": 1,
                        "round": 1,
                        "size": 118000,
                    },
                    {
                        "id": 2,
                        "investor": 2,
                        "round": 1,
                        "size": 183000,
                    },
                ]
            }
        ]
    },
```

Currently, my viewsets extend `get_queryset` as so:

```
class CompanyViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    def get_queryset(self):
        user = self.request.user
        investor = Investor.objects.get(user=user)
        companies = Company.objects.filter(rounds__investments__investor=investor)
        return companies
```

It retrieves the investments that belong to the investor, but when it takes those investments again to retrieve the rounds, it grabs the round with ALL investors.

How can i write this such that it only displays the investments that below to the Investor?

Here are my models:

```
class Company(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100)

class Round(PolymorphicModel):
    company = models.ForeignKey(Company, related_name='rounds', blank=True, null=True)

class Investment(PolymorphicModel):
    investor = models.ForeignKey(Investor, related_name='investor')
    size = models.BigIntegerField(default=0)
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Your description of what happens is pretty unclear. What does "when it takes those investments again" mean? Anyway, I'm guessing what you need to do is to use `.prefetch_related` and a [Prefetch](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/ref/models/querysets/#prefetch-objects) object.

```
from django.db.models import Prefetch

class CompanyViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    def get_queryset(self):
        user = self.request.user
        investor = Investor.objects.get(user=user)
        companies = Company.objects.filter(
            rounds__investments__investor_id=investor.id
        ).prefetch_related(Prefetch(
            'rounds__investments',
            queryset=Investment.objects.filter(
                investor_id=investor.pk,
            ),
        ))
        return companies
```

I haven't tested this snippet but it should give you a pointer in the right direction. I also optimized the `investor` lookup to check the id only, this will save you an unnecessary indirection.

Comment: yes, this is exactly what i'm looking for...thank you!